# block hours in a datetimepicker

Tags: c#, visual-studio, datetimepicker

I have a datetimepicker in C # and I would like to block or allow the user to select times outside the range of 7:00 to 18:00, any ideas?
for example in the dateTimePicker1_ValueChanged validate whether the selected time is outside that range send a message to the user

Comment: WinForms? Where is this control?

Answer (score 2):

In case of C# winforms, you can set custom format of DateTimePicker like this-

```
dateTimePicker1 = new DateTimePicker();
dateTimePicker1.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom;
dateTimePicker1.CustomFormat = "HH:mm"; // Only use hours and minutes
dateTimePicker1.ShowUpDown = true;
```

And then in `dateTimePicker1_ValueChanged` event you can validate range of 7:00 to 18:00.

Full list of format options here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datetimepicker.customformat%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

See if this helps.

Answer (score 0):

When the user select a date post it to your controller class using AJAX, validate the hours on c#, then send back a validation status to your view